# What was the call sign of the clone pilot that helped Obi-Wan and Anakin?

Tags: star-wars

What was the call sign of the clone pilot that helped Obi-Wan and Anakin reach the Invisible Hand in the opening battle?

Sorry I don't in which movie this takes place, I don't know why but I friend needed to know this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His name is [Odd Ball](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Odd_Ball). Coincidental that I just watched this scene yesterday.